# How to Load a Arc layer from json data through coding using reacJs?

Tags: reactjs, kepler.gl, kepler

Need to load a json data dynamically for arc layer

```
data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        startpoint: "bengaluru",
        endpoint: "Mysore",
        startlat: "12.9547899",
        startlng: "77.6006445",
        endlat: "12.3106368",
        endlng: ",76.5656491"
    }
];
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your requirement?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.